# Stop a storyboard from executing

Tags: xaml, storyboard

I have a style trigger that causes my stackpanel to fade in and out with mouseover. I would like to add a checkbox to my stackpanel that will cause it to stay open when checked. How can I stop a storyboard in XAML when my checkbox is checked?

```
<StackPanel Width="25" Opacity="0" Margin="0,0,0,5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
DockPanel.Dock="Right" Background="#FFEEEEEE">
<StackPanel.Style>
    <Style>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Control.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="CloseStoryBoard" />
                    <BeginStoryboard Name="OpenStoryBoard">
                        <Storyboard DecelerationRatio="0.8">
                            <DoubleAnimation 
Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Width)" To="600" />
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" 
To=".95" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </Trigger.EnterActions>
                <Trigger.ExitActions>
                    <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="OpenStoryBoard" />
                    <BeginStoryboard Name="CloseStoryBoard">
                        <Storyboard DecelerationRatio="0.8">
                            <DoubleAnimation 
Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Width)" To="25.0" />
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" 
To="0.0" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </Trigger.ExitActions>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</StackPanel.Style>
<CheckBox Content"Keep Open" />
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I am answering this, credit goes to Zafar above in getting me started. There was one more condition that needed to be added to his suggestion to get exactly the solution I was looking for. I wanted to post the complete solution in case anyone needs this functionality. Below is a StackPanel that fades in and out with the mouseover/out action. It stays open if the checkbox is checked, regardless of mouse position. And goes back to using the mouse over/out once the checkbox is unchecked. I put opacity at 1 for testing, but be sure to set your opacity as needed.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
<ControlTemplate x:Key="SlideoutResource" TargetType="ContentControl">
    <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <StackPanel Name="SlideoutStackPanel" Width="25" Opacity="1" Margin="0,0,0,5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Background="#FFEEEEEE">
            <CheckBox Name="KeepOpenCheckBox" Content="Keep Open" />
        </StackPanel>
        <Rectangle Name="DummyPlaceHolder" /> <!-- This placeholder is needed to make the fade work. -->
    </DockPanel>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition x:Name="MouseOverCondition" SourceName="SlideoutStackPanel" Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                <Condition SourceName="KeepOpenCheckBox" Property="IsChecked" Value="False"/>
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="SlideoutStackPanel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(StackPanel.Width)" To="600" Duration="0:0:1" />
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="SlideoutStackPanel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(StackPanel.Opacity)" To="1" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
        </MultiTrigger>
        <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition SourceName="KeepOpenCheckBox" Property="IsChecked" Value="True"/>
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="SlideoutStackPanel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(StackPanel.Width)" To="600" Duration="0:0:1" />
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="SlideoutStackPanel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(StackPanel.Opacity)" To="1" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
        </MultiTrigger>
        <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition x:Name="MouseOutCondition" SourceName="SlideoutStackPanel" Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False"/>
                <Condition SourceName="KeepOpenCheckBox" Property="IsChecked" Value="False"/>
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="SlideoutStackPanel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(StackPanel.Width)" To="25" Duration="0:0:1" />
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="SlideoutStackPanel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(StackPanel.Opacity)" To="1" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
            <MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="SlideoutStackPanel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(StackPanel.Width)" To="600" Duration="0:0:1" />
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="SlideoutStackPanel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(StackPanel.Opacity)" To="1" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
        </MultiTrigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
<ContentControl Template="{StaticResource SlideoutResource}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ControlTemplate` instead of StackPanel.Style. But ControlTemplate must declared in Window.Resources. I make this code for you. I hope it works that way which is the you wish.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="myResource" TargetType="ContentControl">
        <StackPanel Name="myStackPanel" Width="25" Background="Black" Opacity="0">
            <CheckBox Name="myCheckBox" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="Keep Open" Foreground="Aqua"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition SourceName="myStackPanel" Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                    <Condition SourceName="myCheckBox" Property="IsChecked" Value="False"/>
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="myStackPanel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(StackPanel.Width)" To="600" Duration="0:0:1" />
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="myStackPanel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(StackPanel.Opacity)" To="1" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
                <MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="myStackPanel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(StackPanel.Width)" To="25" Duration="0:0:1" />
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="myStackPanel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(StackPanel.Opacity)" To="0.0" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
            </MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition SourceName="myCheckBox" Property="IsChecked" Value="True"/>
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="myStackPanel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(StackPanel.Width)" To="600" Duration="0:0:1" />
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="myStackPanel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(StackPanel.Opacity)" To="1" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
                <MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="myStackPanel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(StackPanel.Width)" To="25" Duration="0:0:1" />
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="myStackPanel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(StackPanel.Opacity)" To="0.01" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
            </MultiTrigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<ContentControl Template="{StaticResource myResource}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, this is the problem I have run into. The checkbox works well disabling the storyboard, but fide in and out does not get re-enabled when the checkbox is unchecked. I'm hoping with your suggestion that I can figure it out. If you...or anyone else reading this...have a suggestion, I'd gladly take any suggestions.

Comment: To clarify my above comment. The IsMouseOver works like it should until the checkbox is checked to keep the panel open (when the mouse is not over the panel). When the checkbox is unchecked, the IsMouseOver does not work anymore. Any suggestions would be a great help.